# Android studio : dart:ui

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I can't send my test app to my mobile phone

Even after updating it keeps giving this error in bad Android Studio: C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: "Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform. import 'dart:ui' as ui show Canvas, Paint, Path;"

I already tried to update the fluter

Comment: 1.make sure to open project root directory, 2.flutter clean and rebuild, 3.if you've made some changes `flutter upgrade --force`